# PHP ucword mysql insert

Tags: php

I am having a problem capiltalizing the first letter of the "ondeck" insert.  I am trying to use ucwords but I am unsure of where to put that in the following statement:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form2")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO updates (windowStatus, onDeck, updateComments, username) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['windowStatus'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['onDeck'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['updateComments'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"));
```

Please advise.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP´s `ucfirst` capitalizes the first letter of a string. See https://www.php.net/ucfirst

So to capitalize you probaply want to

```
GetSQLValueString(ucfirst($_POST['onDeck']), "text")
```

Or `ucwords` if that´s what you need.
Assuming `GetSQLValueString` is some sort of sql injection security. Otherwise, you might want to read up on SQL injection techniques

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection